# Mirror udp traffic for IPv6

Tags: linux, iptables, ip6tables

I have four Virtual Machines: **A**, **B**, **C**, **D**.

Machines connected by the following way through the Internal Network of Virtual Box `A <-> C`, `B <-> C`, `D <-> C`

Machine **C** - central node in this star network topology.

Machine **D** sending udp packets to **A** machine, but **C** must duplicate all udp traffic from **D** to **B**.

Machine **C** has three interfaces:

`eth0` with IP `2000::ffff:705:a02/120`

`eth1` with IP `2000::ffff:705:b02/120`

`eth2` with IP `2000::ffff:705:c02/120`

Machine **A**:

`eth0` with IP `2000::ffff:705:a01/120`

Machine **B**:

`eth0` with IP `2000::ffff:705:b01/120`

Machine **C**:

`eth0` with IP `2000::ffff:705:c01/120`

I've enabled forwarding in **C** and add next rule:

`ip6tables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -d 2000::ffff:705:a01 -p udp -j TEE --gateway 2000::ffff:705:b01`

But this rule doesn't really work (I'm sending udp datagrams by `nc`)

The strange thing, but for the IPv4 configuration absolutely the same actions work perfectly

Comment: `/120` is a strange (unusual) mask for IPv6. Why not `/64`?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek this is condition of university lab work :(